# Should visitors need to load images to be able to read text?

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

See this meta discussion on another site [IS the site supposed to look like this?](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4120/is-the-site-supposed-to-look-like-this)

When you turn off image loading in your browser and visit the site you are presented with this:

[image]

When you load images a white background is loaded which provides very much better contrast for the blue text.

Obviously the site cannot be fully used without loading images (but I am curious about how blind users manage) but most people visiting sites on SE network will not have accounts.  They'll have done a web search, and they'll click a result.  They do not need the vote buttons or the flags or any of that interface stuff.  But they do need to be able to read the text.  For those people "reading an answer" is "using the site".

Thus: **should visitors need to load images in order to be able to read the text on sites in the SE network?**

Comment: I assume blind users use some sort of a screen reader that cares little about the color of the page. Having said that, we'll be fixing this.

Comment: @AnnaLear There [are blind users on Mi Yodeya](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/45234/5323), FWIW. I don't know how they manage, though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Jin just pushed a fix for this. Should be live in the next production build. Thanks for the report!